# Is there an implementation of libjpeg in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, libjpeg

I am writing some python code that needs [libjpeg](http://www.ijg.org/) . I searched for it on the Internet, and I couldn't find an implement of libjpeg in python. I would like to be able to access, DCT coefficient values, quantization tables, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: A JPEG decoder in pure Python: http://davidf.sjsoft.com/files/pyjpeg/TonyJpegDecoder.py.

Comment: And since I needed one, an encoder as well (only for greyscale images): https://github.com/reinhrst/pygreypeg

Answer (score 1):

That would be the [`jpeg`](http://docs.python.org/library/jpeg.html) module. However, typically the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is preferred for image manipulation.

Comment: Yes and No. I would like to be able to access the DCT coefficient values, quantization table, etc.

Comment: I am not aware of a Python library with more extensive `libjpeg` binding than the two mentioned above; you might have to write such yourself (http://www.theonlineoasis.co.uk/scriptslibraries/pythonlibjpeg.html might be useful as a starting point).

Comment: Preferred by who?  PIL falls short of production-quality and I avoid it for serious use.  (For example, it doesn't even use libpng for decoding PNGs; it has its own implementation which isn't robust, throwing unexpected exceptions when it sees corrupt or incomplete files.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a mac, this might help:  http://jetfar.com/libjpeg-and-python-imaging-pil-on-snow-leopard/ If you're not on a mac, it may give you some ideas on how to proceed on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

"WIP Python interface to libjpeg to access DCT coefficients"
Take a look [here](https://github.com/wartman4404/pyjpeg-dct).